# Touchpad buttons have stopped working on Dell laptop

Tags: touchpad, dell

Recently the lower two touchpad buttons on my Dell laptop have stopped working. There is a second set of touchpad buttons above the touchpad under the space bar and these are working as expected. However, I'd prefer to use the lower buttons as usual, as this is more ergonomic and what I'm accustomed to. If I plug in a USB mouse then that works as expected. It's just the lower touchpad buttons that have gone awry.

Can anyone suggest what I can do to diagnose the issue? Are there drivers that I can reinstall or upgrade that may have an effect?

Dell Latitude 7480, Ubuntu 18.04 LTS

Thanks in advance for any comments or suggestions!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this by ordering a new part (the two buttons) and installing it into the laptop. Everything works as expected now, so this was a hardware malfunction rather than a configuration setting gone awry.

Answer (score 0):

You should see a check box under the mouse settings to enable and disable the touch pad.
[see here](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SynapticsTouchpad)

Comment: The touchpad itself is working as expected, i.e. I can move the pointer/cursor. However, the bottom two buttons are disabled and clicking on them has no effect.